# SSL certificate to protect spoofing of API server

Tags: tls, certificates, validation

I have a program written in Python that checks the validity of its license key with a remote server. Am I right that an SSL certificate would make it possible to prevent spoofing (host redirects for example) of the remote server? And if so, is there a difference between using an official SSL certificate from an SSL provider, or is it perfectly okay to use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Please also review this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code). If the attacker can modify the python program she will not bother calling the license server, not mentioning verifying the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing the certificate is pre-installed with the python program, then you are right: only your server will be able to identify itself to the client.

In this setup, from a security perspective, the difference between a self-signed certificate and one signed by a trusted CA is that if your server's private key was to be compromised, someone might identify a fake server as the valid one to the client which would not detect it, and you wouldn't be able to revoke this certificate. Note that this can be a very serious issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The certificate will indeed be included with the program. How would it be possible for someone to obtain the private key? Is it only possible through direct file access, or other ways?

Comment: If the private key is stored on the server only, then yes the attacker would need to compromise the server to access it. This can be achieved by many different ways, e.g. exploitation of a vulnerability on the server, password stealing from the server's administrator, etc.